# How to add Calculated Member to Pivot Table via Python win32

Tags: excel, vba, python-3.x, pivot-table, win32com

I'm trying to add a calculated column into this pivot table that is being generated via a python script with `import win32com.client`.

Code is posted below that is generating the pivot table. I'm not sure how to add a column. In VBA it would be `wb.PivotTable.CalculatedField.Add` but that didn't work (at least the syntax I tried).

I'm trying to calculate `[OoCUnits] / [GrossUnits]`

```
#Make Pivot version with four weeks data
Excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
win32c = win32com.client.constants
wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open(filename)
ws3 = wb.Worksheets('Dataset')

cl1 = ws3.Cells(1,1)
cl2 = ws3.Cells(max_row,max_col)
PivotSourceRange = ws3.Range(cl1,cl2)
ws3.Activate()
PivotSourceRange.Select()
wb.Sheets.Add (After=wb.Sheets(3))
ws4 = wb.Worksheets(4)
ws4.Name = 'Pivot'

cl3 = ws4.Cells(4,1)
PivotTargetRange = ws4.Range(cl3,cl3)
PivotTableName = 'OoCPivot'

#Make Pivot Table
PivotCache = wb.PivotCaches().Create(SourceType=win32c.xlDatabase, SourceData=PivotSourceRange, Version=win32c.xlPivotTableVersion14)
PivotTable = PivotCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination=PivotTargetRange, TableName=PivotTableName, DefaultVersion=win32c.xlPivotTableVersion14)

PivotTable.PivotFields('Product Name').Orientation = win32c.xlRowField
PivotTable.PivotFields('Product Name').Position = 1
PivotTable.PivotFields('Customer Number').Orientation = win32c.xlPageField
PivotTable.PivotFields('Customer Number').Position = 1
PivotTable.PivotFields('Customer Name').Orientation = win32c.xlPageField
PivotTable.PivotFields('Customer Name').Position = 2
PivotTable.PivotFields('Week Ending Date').Orientation = win32c.xlColumnField
PivotTable.PivotFields('Week Ending Date').Position = 1
DataField = PivotTable.AddDataField(PivotTable.PivotFields('GrossUnits'))
DataField.NumberFormat = '#0.00'
DataField = PivotTable.AddDataField(PivotTable.PivotFields('OoCUnits'))
DataField.NumberFormat = '#0.00'
```

I'm inserting the values with the `DataField`. The script is not presenting any issues as is.

EDIT: The exact code I implemented to solve. The last two lines are just formatting. I'm including in case it helps someone else.

```
CalcField = PivotTable.CalculatedFields().Add('OoC Unit %','= OoCUnits / GrossUnits')
DataField = PivotTable.AddDataField(PivotTable.PivotFields('OoC Unit %'))
DataField.NumberFormat = '#%'
PivotTable.DisplayErrorString = True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the method is `PivotTable.CalculatedFields().Add()` according to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.calculatedfields.add). Consider placing below at bottom:

```
CalcField = PivotTable.CalculatedFields().Add("OC_GrossPct", "= OoCUnits / GrossUnits")

PivotTable.PivotFields("OC_GrossPct").Orientation = win32c.xlDataField
```

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I needed to go `PivotTable.CalculatedFields().Add("OC_GrossPct", "= OoCUnits / GrossUnits")` for it to work, with the extra ().